# Firebase chat fetch and delete particular chat call firebase real time socket continuously

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have two functions here one for listing all chat created by user and one for delete chat after sometime. so, when i tried to load user all chat it will check chat time is ended than it will deleted while loading. when i go for users chat it will perform all things which i mentioned and what i get page getting reload every 0.5 seconds.

**Fetch Messages Function**

```
///Fetches and returns all the conversations for the user with passed in email
    public func getAllConversations(for email:String, completion: @escaping(Result<[Conversation], Error>)->Void){
        database.child("\(email)/conversations").observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [[String: Any]] else{
                completion(.failure(DatabaseError.failedToFetch))
                return
            }
            let conversations: [Conversation] = value.compactMap { dictionary in
                guard let conversationId = dictionary["id"] as? String,
                      let name = dictionary["name"] as? String,
                      let otherUserEmail = dictionary["other_user_email"] as? String,
                      let latestMessage = dictionary["latest_message"] as? [String:Any],
                      let date = latestMessage["date"] as? String,
                      let message = latestMessage["message"] as? String,
                      let isRead = latestMessage["is_read"] as? Bool else{
                          return nil
                      }
                
                let latestMessageObject = LatestMessage(date: date,
                                                        text: message,
                                                        isRead: isRead)
                return Conversation(id: conversationId,
                                    name: name,
                                    otherUserEmail: otherUserEmail,
                                    latestMessage: latestMessageObject)
            }
            completion(.success(conversations))
        })
    }
```

**Checking For Expiration Chat**

```
public func listenForMessages(id:String, completion: @escaping (Bool, String, Date) -> Void) {
        DatabaseManager.shared.getAllMessagesForConversation(with: id, completion: { [weak self] result in
            guard let _ = self else {return}
            switch result {
            case .success(let messages):
                print("success in getting messages:\(messages)")
                guard !messages.isEmpty else{
                    print("messages are empty")
                    return
                }
                print(messages)
                guard let date = messages.first?.sentDate else {
                    return
                }
                let tempCalendar = Calendar.current
                let oneHourAfter = tempCalendar.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: date)
                let (val,isNeedToDelete) = CommonClass().getDiffrenceBetweenDates(date: oneHourAfter!.timeIntervalSince1970)
                print("============REMAIN TIME DB============",oneHourAfter)
                print("============REMAIN DATE DB============",val)
                if isNeedToDelete {
                    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                        self?.deleteOldChats(id: id, completion: { isDeleted in
                            print(isDeleted)
                            completion(true,String(),date)
                        })
                    }
                }else {
                    completion(false,val,oneHourAfter ?? Date())
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("failed to get messages:\(error)")
            }
        })
    }
```

**Delete Messages Function**

```
private func deleteOldChats(id:String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    DatabaseManager.shared.deleteConversation(conversationId: id, completion: { [weak self] success in
        guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
        if success{
            print("Deleted Succesfully")
            completion(true)
        }else {
            print("Not able to delete")
            completion(false)
        }
    })
}
```

As per my understanding firebase use sockets and those are updated whenever we perform CRUD Operation that is the issue over here.

i want to stop reload data every time and data needs to be deleted properly without affecting main thread.

Comment: Do you want to [read the data only once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes exactly what i want and once we fetch completed it decide which one need to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks To [@FrankvanPuffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)

i found easy answer on firebase [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once).

i made changes on `database` in my code

```
database.child("\(email)/conversations").observe(.value)
```

to

```
database.child("\(email)/conversations").observeSingleEvent(of: .value)
```